# How to index big text fields in Lucene 4.10.1

Tags: lucene

I'm taking my first steps in Lucene (Version 4.10.1) and my current goal is to index a text field from a file which is 100KB big. Because the text doesn't fit into a string, I've put the text from the file into a byte array. But when I run the program Lucene says `Fields with BytesRef values cannot be indexed`.

So the question is: How to index big text fields?

Here's the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File("testIndex"));
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_1, analyzer);
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, conf);
            Path path = Paths.get("text.txt");
            byte[] text = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++) {
                Document doc = new Document();
                FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
                fieldType.setIndexed(true);
                fieldType.setTokenized(true);
                fieldType.setStored(true);
                fieldType.setOmitNorms(true);
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(false);
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(false);
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(false);
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(false);
                Field title = new Field("text"+i, text, fieldType);

                doc.add(title);

                indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            }
            Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Elapsed Time in  Ms: "+elapsedTime);

            indexWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a `StringBuilder`.

Code:

```
            Path path = Paths.get("text.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String text = stringBuilder.toString();
```